# Android - Check if external server is online

Tags: java, android, ping

I want to check if my server is online before launching any activity with an online component.

I have tried using ping

```
runtime.exec("ping -c 1 google.com");  
proc.waitFor();  
int exit = proc.exitValue();
```

but this will always give either exit code 1 or 2, never 0, even when I know the server is online..

I have also tried

```
Online=InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com").isReachable(10000);
```

But apparently this function is flakey as hell with external servers, and as such it doesn't work either.

Surely such a basic function as checking if a server is online should be pretty straightforward? does anyone have any ideas I haven't tried yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try connecting to the server, using whatever protocol you are going to use "for real". Just because a server responds to a `ping` does not mean that the server is running for what you need it for. So, for example, if you are going to make requests of a Web service, perform some simple HTTP operation.

Comment: ythat's generally fine if the server returns something like 500 etc. but when it does it for real and the actual host is properly offline it force crashes the app for some reason :/ (despite the fact there's a timeout specified and the whole thing's around a try/catch)

Comment: @user530501: It gives you a 500 return code when you try to fetch `/robots.txt`? Harsh.

Comment: yeah, actually you gave me the idea that if i just check if response is null then that works fine so far, cheers :)